# Отсуствует src в Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Кто нибудь объяснит,почему в проекте у меня отсутствует папка sources(src по умолчанию)?Как ее вернуть?

Comment: представление проекта поменяйте в левом верхнем углу

Comment: представление проекта еще бы знать где оно

Comment: слева вверху в окне, где отображаются все папки в виде структуры, есть переключатель в виде маленького треугольника-стрелочки

Comment: Нужно больше информации. Сами ли вы создавали проект или качнули с чьего-нибудь репозитория? 
Может у вас родственники ночью удалили всю папку. Скрин дайте папок проекта, тогда нам станет яснее.

Comment: Как оказалось,папка действительно была удалена.Как мне уже ответили надо было right-click your source folder, and choose "Mark directory as - Source root".Всем спасибо за помощь,я уж вчера отчаялся что никто не ответит/

Comment: "Mark directory as - Source root" - это немного другое, но главное, что разобрались и узнали что то новое и полезное для себя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробуйте поменять представление отображения проекта. По умолчанию скрываются некоторые папки для удобства. Проверьте, есть ли нужные папки (которые вы хотите отобразить) в проекте на диске?