# Код Java размещённый без src игнорируется Aqua, но работает в IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, aqua

Сразу говорю - [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/506739/%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-src-%D0%B2-intellij-idea) не мой случай.
Папки в принципе нет.
[image: Структура]

Причём код нормально компилируется и запускается через IDEA. Aqua не находит классы (не определяет файлы как классы):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать зайти в настройки проекта: "File" -> "Project Structure" (или сочетание клавиш Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S) и проверить следующие вещи:

Стоит убедиться, что исходные пути (Source Paths) настроены правильно. Даже если нет папки src, должна быть указана корневая директория проекта как исходный путь.

Также можно перейти в раздел "Project" -> "Project Compiler Output" и убедиться, что путь к выходной директории компилятора указан правильно. Это место, где компилятор сохраняет скомпилированные классы.

Также советую перейти в раздел "Global Libraries" и убедиться, что библиотеки, необходимые для проекта, правильно настроены. Также можно проверить переменные окружения, особенно CLASSPATH!

Также стоит удостовериться, что конфигурация запуска (если есть) указывает на правильный класс для запуска (скорее всего всё хорошо).

Также могут быть проблемы из-за кеша. Стоит очистить кеш и пересобрать проект.

Как очистить кеш:

Зайдите в "File" (Файл) в верхнем левом углу IntelliJ IDEA.
Выберите "Invalidate Caches / Restart" (Очистить кеш / Перезапустить).
В появившемся диалоговом окне выберите "Invalidate and Restart" (Очистить и перезапустить).

**UPD**:

В настройках проекта в IntelliJ IDEA (File -> Project Structure).
Раздел "Project" -> "Project": корневая папка проекта должны быть добавлена в "Project compiler output" (папка, в которую компилируются классы).

В том же разделе "Project" -> "Project Compiler Output" стоит посмотреть, что указанный путь для компиляции ведет к правильной директории и в этой директории создаются правильные поддиректории, соответствующие пакетам (если они используются).

Код должен быть организован в соответствии с пакетами, указанными в файлах. Например, если у есть класс Starter в пакете com.example, то файл должен быть расположен в подпапке com/example.

Comment: После добавления корневой папки с кодом в `Source Paths` иконки появились, класс нашёлся, но при компиляции через Акву всё равно пишет `Error: Could not find or load main class Starter
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Starter`. Хотя класс был определён (определён как класс для запуска, но всё равно в настройках запуска светиться красным).

Comment: Попробуйте проделать шаги из update.
Ваша проблема действительно не однозначная, поэтому, если вас не затруднит, вы бы могли отправить файлы конфигурации сюда.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

После перезагрузки обоих сред, настройка слетела и в IDEA. Было решено следующим (в обоих средах):

1. Создать `pom.xml` в корне
2. В `Project Structure` -> `Modules` нужно было добавить `Language level` и указать корень в качестве `Sources` для основного пакета
3. При наличии библиотек нужно было перейти в `Project Structure` -> `Libraries`, ПКМ -> `Add to modules...` на каждую.
4. Если проект нашёлся, но библиотеки к нему ещё не подключены, то нужно записать из в `pom.xml` по образцу:

```xml
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>...</groupId>
            <artifactId>...</artifactId>
            <version>...</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- При необходимости добавить так же-->
    </dependencies>
</project>
```